# Perform function after Facebook share

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, api

I was wonder if there was a way to confirm that a user has shared a post from my website, I'm trying to have an email sent out to the user after they share my post. The emails will all be collected from my site, not from the facebook api. I just need to know if there is any way to call back a confirmation on the sharing system.

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: How about FB API? http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/facebook-publish-to-wall-with-popup-or-dialog-and-call-back/

Answer (score -1):

Just add a new "myfunction(); after the first one.

```
OnClick="Window.open();myfunction();"
```

Comment: That will perform the function before the user even shares our post. I need to find out how to perform a callback after the user submits the post.

Comment: @JackSniper I was looking for the same solution. Did you find anything anyway?